# How to compile C Extension for Python

Tags: linux, python

I am attempting to install `https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py` (on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian)
by running `sudo python setup.py install`

This fails with error

```
spi.c:20:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
```

Presumably I need to install some library but the "documentation" with SPI-Py is almost non-existent.

I have no problem running other `c` programs.

There is a `/usr/lib/pypy-upstream/include/Python.h`

Comment: Can you try `locate Python.h` and show its output?

Comment: Can you show the output of `python -V` to check the version of Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the C compiler (probably gcc) cannot find Python.h.  You can either edit the source of SPI-Py to point to PyPy's version, or you can install the appropriate python-dev package to perform the SPI-Py install.

### Install python-dev

This is the least intrusive method, but it may be considered "bulky" since you already have PyPy on the system.  If you're using Python 2, get that dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Or, to install the Python 3 dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

After you have the appropriate dev package, try to install SPI-Py again.  If it succeeds, you can safely remove the Python dev package, if you wish.  To remove the Python 2 dev package:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-dev
```

Or, to remove the Python 3 dev package:

```
sudo apt-get purge python3-dev
```

After either command, you can remove their dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

### Modify SPI-Py

Please note that I have not tested this solution.  To force SPI-Py to use PyPy's "Python.h", you'll probably have to edit the spi.c file.  Change the following line:

```
module1 = Extension('spi', sources = ['spi.c'])
```

to:

```
module1 = Extension('spi',
                    include_dirs = ['/usr/lib/pypy-upstream/include/'],
                    sources = ['spi.c'])
```

After that, try to install SPI-Py again.

Answer (score 3):

You should install the package `python-dev`.